# Access a demo service in remote Kubernetes cluster using ingress

Tags: minikube, nginx-ingress

I have a minikube installed on a Linux machine, and I tried following the [Deploy Hello World App](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/)
to get access to the demo service from outside (my browser).

```
$ kubectl get service web
NAME   TYPE       CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
web    NodePort   10.103.184.174   <none>        8080:30068/TCP   17h
~$ minikube service web --url
http://192.168.49.2:30068
```

But when trying to access this url from my browser I'm getting:

> Connection timeout. The server at 192.168.49.2 is taking too long to respond.

I tried doing port forwarding (on Linux machine), but it didn't help as well!

```
~$ kubectl port-forward svc/web 30068:8080
```

Note::
There is a ping to that ip from inside the linux machine, but no ping from outside.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What am I missing?

What you are missing is the basics of networking knowledge. Your minikube is most likely running in a VM. This VM has assigned a virtual net interface with an IP address that is known only to the mentioned linux machine it's running on and no other device in your network is aware of it, and therefore has no idea where to send the packets. Connection timeout suggests that packets get dropped somewhere (most likely on a router but firewall can also be a cause in some cases).

#### What can you do to solve it?

Try starting minikube with `--driver=none`, so that minikube doesn't start in a vm and gets direct access to host's network interface an its IP address.

```
$ minikube start --driver=none
```

Other solution would be using kubectl port-forward. The way you used it is almost correct. You only forgot one thing: kubectl port-forward by default binds on loopback/localhost. You need to explicitly tell it to bind on all interfaces so that it can be accessed from the outside. Adding `--address=0.0.0.0` should do the job, but remember to use ip of the linux machine, not the minikube to access the website.

```
$ kubectl port-forward svc/web 30068:8080 --address=0.0.0.0
Forwarding from 0.0.0.0:30068 -> 8080
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I deleted my minikube cluster and tried to start a new clean one as suggested in your first option but got: "Exiting due to GUEST_MISSING_CONNTRACK: Sorry, Kubernetes 1.20.2 requires conntrack to be installed in root's path"... so moved on to test the second suggestion with port forwarding (using the <machine host name>:<new given port>) and now I'm getting: "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading."

Comment: Try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/181115/how-to-fix-the-connection-to-the-server-was-reset-while-the-page-was-loading

Comment: Didn't help, it doesn't work on other browsers as well (in chrom for example getting: This page isn’t working, <host> didn’t send any data.), in the port forwarding window I can see a connection refused message: Handling connection for 31111
Handling connection for 31111
E0420 10:59:36.808959 2861901 portforward.go:400] an error occurred forwarding 31111 -> 8070: error forwarding port 8070 to pod 1b1f0e703f271ed3d39874609af10870eb679b7dee6018b293645d22ae378f79, uid : exit status 1: 2021/04/20 10:59:36 socat[12615] E connect(5, AF=2 127.0.0.1:8070, 16): Connection refused

Comment: btw, I changed to 8070 instead of 8080 cause I have another tomcat apps running in that machine using 8080, so wanted to distinguish between them.

Comment: Can you acccess this port from the linux host? if you can then its firewall most likely, if you cannot, port is not open

Comment: Yes seems so, from inside: curl http://<host>:31111/ getting
curl: (52) Empty reply from server (NOT connection refused). I asked our IT and they can't open ports in that machine

Comment: Empty reply suggests that sth accepted the connection and closed it shortly after that without sending any data. My best bet is that it is a corporate firewall blocking.

Comment: I tried exposing the service with --type=LoadBalancer and it worked (doing the port forward as you suggested) ! I red in this article (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/expose/expose-intro/)

Answer (score 0):

This what I did to access minikube app remotely from another computer.

- Remote terminal 1 and keep opening:

```
minikube tunnel --bind-address='0.0.0.0'
```

- Remote terminal 2:

```
kubectl get all
curl localhost
```

- local terminal 1 (create ssh tunnel to remote and also keep it opening)

```
ssh -L 8000:localhost:80 ssh_user@remote_server
```

- Open browser in local to access http://localhost:8000